# How to display different pages based upon form input value (ie: zip code)? jQuery or .PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zipcode

Is there a jQuery, javascript, or .php script that would allow me to display different pages based upon a list of zip codes? For example, if the user enters a zip code within a list of 'valid' zips then pageA.php would display, if not then pageB.php would be displayed. These zip code values could be manually listed out, or be contained within a .csv file, whatever is easiest.

The page displayed after input would be based upon user input like:

```
<input name="zipcode" id="zipcode" type="text" />
```

the valid zip codes ideally would be listed as:

```
<script>
var zipcodelist = ['12345','12346','12347','12348'];
```

---

**UPDATED SOLUTION**
this is the code i'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var zipCodes = ['92056', '90210', '92121', '92101'];

    $('#zip_form').submit(function(){
        $('#id_div_one, #id_div_two').hide();
        var theZip = $('#id_zip_code').val();
        if(jQuery.inArray(theZip,zipCodes) > -1) {
            $('#id_div_one').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#id_div_two').fadeIn();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of a framework for this app?  Something like CodeIgniter, for example?

Comment: how would the user submit his zipcode?

Comment: You could just make a page.php that outputs different HTML based on the zip code input.

Comment: @ametren no there is no app framework in place, just basic brochure html site right now

Comment: @PedroL. i updated the question above to reflect the user input

Answer (score 1):

You would probably just take the posted value for the zip code and then in your application logic just redirect to the page you want.  For example in PHP:

```
$special_zip_codes = array(
    '10000',
    '10002',
    '10003' // and so forth
);

$zip = $_POST['zip_code'];
// need to add whatever validation/sanitation of zip code value here

if(in_array($zip, $special_zip_codes)) {
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/fileA.php');
} else {
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/fileB.php');
}
exit();
```

Comment: thanks mike, unfortunately i think i need a bit more info. i would like to list the zip codes in a .csv and then check that list on form submission and if the zip code is on that .csv then display pageA.php. if the zip code is not on that list then display pageB.php. Unfortunately, i don't know the code to execute this at all.. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @aaronb I have changed my sample to show you taking the zip code values from an array (something that you ultimately would be working with if pulling from an external file anyway) and redirecting to one of two pages. If you don't specifically need the csv file and the values are not going to be changing all the time, just configuring the zip codes in php should be fine.  Or just list them all on separate lines of a file and use the file() function to read them into an array.

Comment: @mike thanks for your help! i ended up going with a javascript solution but thanks so much - updated the request above with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Make a php file which will take the data from the html file ( which has the pincode) say using post or get
And then check from the excel sheet or DB the pincode and do what is required.